# AudioManager setCommunicationDevice is not working on Android 12

Tags: android, react-native, android-audiomanager, speaker, react-native-native-module

I'm developing a mini native (Java) SDK to turn ON/OFF speaker for a react-native app for calls , because React-Native Incall Manager doesn't work properly on Android 12.

Module is working good on Android 11, but since setSpeakerOn method from AudioManager is deprecated for newest SDK, on Android 12 there are some issues. I took the code snippet from official [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager#setCommunicationDevice(android.media.AudioDeviceInfo)) and adapted it. Even if boolean
`result = audioManager.setCommunicationDevice(device)` returns **TRUE** , it doesn't change the speaker state.

**Permission**

> android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />

**AudioModule.java**

```
public class AudioModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {
    private AudioManager audioManager;
    private static final String TAG = "AudioModule";
    private static ReactApplicationContext reactContext;
AudioModule(ReactApplicationContext context) {
    super(context);
    reactContext = context;
    audioManager = ((AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE));

}


@Override
public String getName() {
    return "AudioModule";
}

@ReactMethod
public void setSpeakerState(Boolean speakerState) {
    try {
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
            if (speakerState) {
                setCommunicationDevice(AudioDeviceInfo.TYPE_BUILTIN_SPEAKER);
            } else {
                audioManager.clearCommunicationDevice(); //turn off speaker
            }
        } else {
            audioManager.setMode(speakerState ? AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION : AudioManager.MODE_NORMAL);
            audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(speakerState);

        }
        Toast.makeText(reactContext, "speakerStatus " + audioManager.isSpeakerphoneOn(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "AudioModule setSpeaker", e);
    }
}


@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.S)
public void setCommunicationDevice(Integer targetDeviceType) {
    List<AudioDeviceInfo> audioDevices = audioManager.getAvailableCommunicationDevices();
    for (AudioDeviceInfo device : audioDevices) {
        if (device.getType() == targetDeviceType) {
            audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION );
            boolean result = audioManager.setCommunicationDevice(device);

            break;
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:** Native Module for React-Native is working properly on Android 11 OS and is showing Toast on Android 12 and 13 (tested on physical devices)

**UPDATED:**
Tried also with **IncallService** interface:
import android.telecom.InCallService;

```
public class CallService extends InCallService {
private static CallService sInstance;

CallService() {
    sInstance = this;
}


public static CallService getInstance() {
    return sInstance;
}
}
```

**Method called**

```
@ReactMethod
public void toggleSpeaker() {

    boolean isSpeakerOn = audioManager.isSpeakerphoneOn();
    int earpiece = CallAudioState.ROUTE_WIRED_OR_EARPIECE;
    int speaker = CallAudioState.ROUTE_SPEAKER;

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
        callService.getInstance().setAudioRoute(isSpeakerOn ? earpiece : speaker);
    } else {
        audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(!isSpeakerOn);
    }
    Toast.makeText(reactContext, "speakerStatus " + audioManager.isSpeakerphoneOn(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

Logcat returns the next message:

> android.hardware.audio.service: Failed to fetch the lookup information
> of the device

Comment: have you found any solution?

Comment: @SujithSManjavana not yet

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue with android 12 and even with some android 11 devices. When I call `am.setCommunicationDevice(earpieceDevice)` it was returning `true` but the audio was still playing on loudspeaker. Then I force enabled `NORMAL_MODE` by calling  `am.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_NORMAL)`, and now it's working. Weird!

```
private fun setAudioDevice(){
 am.mode = AudioManager.MODE_NORMAL
 val speakerDevice: AudioDeviceInfo? = getAudioDevice(AudioDeviceInfo.TYPE_BUILTIN_SPEAKER)
 am.setCommunicationDevice(speakerDevice)
}

 private fun getAudioDevice(type: Int): AudioDeviceInfo? {
        val audioDevices = am.getDevices(AudioManager.GET_DEVICES_OUTPUTS)
        for (deviceInfo in audioDevices) {
            if (type == deviceInfo.type) return deviceInfo
        }
        return null
    }
```

Comment: how about to turn on the speaker :) ?

Comment: Just get the ``` AudioDeviceInfo``` of your speaker device and call ```am.setCommunicationDevice(yourSpeakerDevice)```

Comment: already tried                 setCommunicationDevice(AudioDeviceInfo.TYPE_BUILTIN_SPEAKER);

Comment: You should loop through all available devices then pass the proper device to ```setCommunicationDevice()``` function.

Comment: On some Samsung phones, you have to adjust the volume slider to make it work (even if the volume is full, the point is there should be a value change in volume slider)

Comment: thanks :) but as you can see on the code above, I did the same :)

Comment: Which device are you using?

Comment: In my case ```AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION``` was causing the issue. Even if I don't use this mode, android was switching to ```AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION``` by its own right after the stream start. When I force use ```AudioManager.MODE_NORMAL``` it was working fine.

Comment: I use Google Pixel 4A, the problem is that the speaker doesn't work during the call (just If I toggle it with native android call UI)

Comment: This workaround works for me, indeed it is weird, there is some kind of problem related to setMode API

Comment: @andresshoyo Be careful though, On my Samsung android 11 device the microphone volume was very low when I use ```AudioManager.MODE_NORMAL```.

Comment: @SujithSManjavana Yes I noticed that, do you have any suggestion to address that? maybe using adjustVolume api?

Comment: @andresshoyo I didn’t notice any microphone issues with android 12 devices. So,  Currently, I'm using ```AudioManager.MODE_NORMAL``` only on android 12 and higher, and ```AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION``` on older devices. Not the best fix. If you find another fix, please let me know.

Comment: Same with Xiaomi 12 Lite (Android 12) when use `AudioManager.MODE_NORMAL` the volume heard in earbud is very low and still takes audio input from microphone of the phone. I'm guessing target api 31 is released in a hurry and most manufacturers didn't adapt to the new api well.

Comment: Not able to change mode to MODE_NORMAL.
Android was switching to AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION by its own right after the VoIP stream start. And even after adding code "am.mode = AudioManager.MODE_NORMAL" nothing happens and mode remains unchanged(MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION)

Can you guys please confirm you are able to change mode to NORMAL after answering incoming VoIP call. (To turn on speakerPhone)